# Making Hibernate ignore @Transient isXyz() method when I have a mapped getXyz()?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, getter, transient

I am trying to add JPA/Hibernate annotation for mapping to SQL Server, but my legacy code has some unfortunate method naming.  I want for Hibernate to ignore a method (annotated with @Transient), but the method naming seems to be confusing Hibernate...

My "xyz" field is a byte[], to be mapped to an SQL varbinary column.  The getXyz() is annotated as one might expect:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ABCBase {
    ...
    @Column(name = "xyz")
    public byte[] getXyz () { ... }
    public void setXyz () { ... }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately the legacy code also has an isXyz() method.  I know Hibernate looks for get___() and is___(), so I annotated isXyz() @Transient:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc")
public class ABC {
    ...
    // The following method is unfortunately named for Hibernate...
    @Transient
    public boolean isXyz () { ... }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, although Hibernate knows there is a mapped "xyz" field... it forgets (or doesn't care) about the @Transient annotation and tries to use isXyz() instead of getXyz().  This leads to a ClassCastException, because Hibernate gets a Boolean instead of a byte[].

Is there any good way around this besides renaming isXyz()?  I realize that when integrating Hibernate annotations, it's best practice to mind the method naming... but it would be easier if there were an annotation that took care of this.  (I feel like @Transient is only doing half its job.  I'd like something that makes Hibernate ignore the method completely.)

Comment: Annotate the fields instead of methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlanHay.  That isn't feasible in my case because my POJOs have all the "fields" in a Map instead of as member variables.  (That is, ABCBase does not have a "byte[] xyz" field... setXyz() stores the byte[] value in a Map, and getXyz() reads from that Map.)

Any other ways around this?